# Access Timer VBA to send email running only once

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

I have a form with 2 subforms. One subform has a timer for 30 minutes to refresh data which runs fine. The other subform has the following code to send an email at a set time

```
If DLookup("SCHEDULEDATETIME", "TBLSCHEDULERNEW", "SCHEDULETYPE='AWAITREG'") >= Date Then
    End
End If

If TimeValue(Now()) > #9:00:00 AM# Then
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")        
        Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        oMail.Body = "email"
        oMail.Subject = "Test Subject"
        oMail.To = "xxx@xxx.com"
        oMail.Send
        Set oMail = Nothing
        Set oApp = Nothing
End If

strsql = "update TBLSCHEDULERNEW set SCHEDULEDATETIME =trunc(sysdate) WHERE SCHEDULETYPE='AWAITREG';"

With MyCon
    .Open "xxx", "xxx", "xxx"
    .Execute strsql
    .Close
End With
```

I have additional code to check if the email has been sent today already, which works fine

This only runs once. I have to open the form in Design View, and then Form View again for the code to start working. Why could this be?

I need to schedule the email dispatch in this way rather than `SendObject` as I need to attached a formatted Excel spreadsheet.

Edit - I now don't think this is anything to do with sending an email, as code just seem to be called at all - I tested with just a `msgbox`.

Comment: Please share all the code. The current code is not including anything to run it only once.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Done.

Comment: I still don't see any specifics on how the code is called, and why this should only happen once.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The subform has a timer of 60000. The On Timer event has one line SendAwaitingRegReport which calls the code in my question.

Comment: You haven't included that. Why would that make it only run once?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That's my question. I don't want it to run once. I want to know why it is running just once.

Comment: All subs execute only once. Is this code in any kind of Event Subs? Like "Form_open" or something? I guess it should be on `Private Sub Form_Timer()`and make sure your TimeInterval is not 0

Comment: @Gustav This was the issue. I thought that if I put END there, my code would just start again on the next tick. I've now structured the If statement more sensibly. Feel free to put as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And `End` really means that.

Your code will stop and *all* variables will be cleared. Probably not what you want.